# Do Admob work if I upload app on other stores like amazon, 9apps and Getjar instead of Google play store?

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I have uploaded app on the Google play store and then I linked my app with AdMob. But due to some copy right reasons, Google removed my app from the Google play store.

Now I have uploaded the same app on the Getjar(App store). But my AdMob stop working. How could I use Admob on the Getjar or any other store to earn revenue?

I have also checked Leadbolt ad platform but I was not able to found banner ads in it. Please help on this as well.

I would be thankful if someone suggests me any other best alternative of the Admob.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work on different app stores, provided AdMob is available in that country.

In your case, the ad-id associated with your ad is deactivated because the app is removed from the App Store.

Creating another ad id and a new app package name will resolve the problem.

If you are breaching some copyright, then you have to resolve them (removing the infringing assets) before uploading it to other App-stores.

Comment: Thank you Angel, let me do the changes and will update you